# Intermediate value property for derivatives

Tags: real-analysis

I'm going over a proof of a special case of the Intermediate value theorem for derivatives.

It says:

> Consider $a, b\in I$ with $a<b$.
>
> Suppose first that $f'(a)<0<f'(b)$. We will show $\exists x\in(a, b)$
>   such that $f'(x)=0$.
>
> Since $f'$ exists on $[a, b]$, we must have $f$ continuous on $[a, b]$, so the  Extreme Value Theorem implies that $f$ attains its minimum
>   at some point $x\in[a, b]$. This minimum point cannot be an endpoint
>   of $[a, b]$.

I just don't understand this last sentence. Why can't the minimum point be an endpoint of $[a, b]$?

Comment: It can't occur at $a$, since $f'(a)<0$. (There must be points $x$ near $a$ with $x>a$ and $f(x)<f(a)$.)

Comment: @DavidMitra Thanks! That's clear intuitively but how would one rigorously prove it?

Comment: $f'(a)=\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow0^+} {f(a+h)-f(a)\over h }<0\Rightarrow f(a+h)-f(a)<0$ for $h$ sufficiently small.

Answer (score -1):

Since $$f'(a)=\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow0^+} {f(a+h)-f(a)\over h }<0,$$ it follows that  ${f(a+h)-f(a)\over h }<0$ for $h>0$ sufficiently small (with $a+h<b$). From this, it follows that  ${f(a+h)-f(a)  }<0$ for $h>0$ sufficiently small; thus, the minimum can't occur at $x=a$.

A similar argument will show the minimum can't occur at $x=b$.